# Which itemtype should use for TV channels using schema.org?

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I am using schema.org vocabularies for microdata. Which itemtype should I use for TV channels (HBO,Cinimax,Starz,PlayBoy)?

like:

```
<div itemscope itemtype ="http://schema.org/TVChannles">
  <h1 itemprop="name">HBO</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to ask this question on the mailing list that discusses vocabularies, particularly schema.org. It is [public-vocabs@w3.org](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/).

Comment: that's a nice pointer in the right direction, but it's not the answer to the question :( should have been a comment, not an answer.